# How to set template in block for current theme

Tags: layout, template, theme, blocks

I have set template using the following code

```
$this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('catalogsearch/for‌​m.mini.phtml')->toHtml();
```

This calls the template file from the following folder `frontend/base/default/template/catalogsearch/for‌​m.mini.phtml`.

How can I call this from my custom theme (i.e.) `frontend/customtheme/default/template/catalogsearch/for‌​m.mini.phtml` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have configured your `package/theme` correctly in backend (at `System > Configuration  > Design`), then Magento will automatically take your phtml file from your `package\theme` if you have defined your phtml file correctly there.

Magento uses a callback mechanism to fetching the correct file. It first look for a theme file in the configured `package/theme` directory, then the default theme directory (if any) and at last in the `base/default` directory.

So your file is taking from `base/default` directory means, you didnt defined `catalogsearch/for‌​m.mini.phtml` in your theme directory correctly. So check again the template file path and then clear the cache.

Comment: Hi Rajeev, Thank you for your comment, However I have declared correct package name on configuration and I have file on my customtheme folder

Comment: Hi Rajeev, I just checked the error log and found the solution. this was the error  'Not valid template file:frontend/base/default/template/catalogsearch/forâ€Œâ€‹m.mini.phtml'. I just copied the code from some site and this causes the spell mistake. ;-)